# Gravity Forms post/get to get data from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

sadly i have no success retrieving data with a simple ajax request from my mysql database.

I have a gravity from set up with ajax in the shortcode enabled. When i change the selection of the first field, i want a ajax request to be done to retrieve data from the database and to load it into another field depending on the selection of the first field.

The alerts are working so i guess there is something wrong with the jquery request.

Edit: Solution down below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: This is the current solution i am using which is imo the best one. Instead of creating a seperate connection in the php file i am accessing the wordpress functionality.

Here is the code for a gravity form ajax request to get data from a mysql database after a change on a select box has been done.

```
add_filter("gform_pre_render_2", "getdbdata");
    function getdbdata($form){
        ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                jQuery('#input_2_1').bind('change', function()
                {
                  var vdepot_id = jQuery("#input_2_1").val();   

                  jQuery.ajax({
                    async: 'false',
                    type: 'post',
                    global: 'false',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: 'yoursite.com/yourscript.php',
                    data: {
                      virtuellesdepot_id:vdepot_id,
                    },
                    success: function (response) {  
                        jQuery("#input_2_28").val(response.status);
                    }
                  });                       
                });
            });
            </script>
        <?php
        return $form;
        }
```

and that is the php code you need on your server:

```
<?php
if( isset( $_POST['virtuellesdepot_id'] ) )
{
$vdepot_id = $_POST['virtuellesdepot_id'];

define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false ); // Don't load theme support functionality
require_once("../wp-load.php");  //now you can use wp functions
$user_id = get_current_user_id();

//make a security check if user has access to the entry
$user_check = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM usertable WHERE vdepot_id= %d ",  $vdepot_id));
    if($user_check != $user_id){
    header("Location: https://yoursite/no-access/");
    exit();
}

//use any sql query you want
$status = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT status_id FROM table WHERE user_id= %d ",  $user_id));
$arr = array ('status'=>$status);
echo json_encode($arr);

}else{
echo "Fehler bei if isset";
}

?>
```

Comment: Good job.  Usually then I generate a response from PHP to JavaScript for an AJAX request, I generate it as a JSON object. You will need to look at how to se headers in PHP and json_encode() method also.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot to say about your code but as you said you're new to code so let's start small.

A good thing to do when developping for the web is to use the developer's tools that most of the recent browser have.
Especially with Ajax as it could help you figure out what's wrong.

On Firefox or Chrome, you can display it by pressing F12.
It should displauy a new windows (or a panel at the bottomm or on one side of your current opened window).
in this panel, you'll find several tabs, but the one that interest us here is called "Network" .
The network tab display all requests made when loading you page (en even after): try to reload it and you will see it.
Inside the network panel, you will find several "buttons": ALL, XHR JS, CSS, ... allowing you to filter the type of requests to display.
For AJAX request for exemple it is "XHR".

Now If you manipulate your select element (the one you create an action on the "change" with jQuery), you should see youre AJAX request appearse in the panel.

Click on it and you will see details on that was send, and the response recieved :
Headers correspond to your request
Preview and Response display the return of the server (in your case: getrcedepot.php) (preview is just a pretiest (and navigable) version of Response which display the raw response)

You may find some clue of that is the issue (or at least some indications).

Also i you have some error in your JavaScript code, you may find some informations in the "Console" tab of the developper toolbox.

Comment: Ok thanks that helped quite a lot now. The request now works. I updated the code above. The only thing which i dont know is how can i get the sql query into the variable in the javascript function?

Comment: Do describe that in more detail: How can i get the "echo 5555555;" from the php into my variable in javascript?